# AMD FX CPU drivers/patch

Tags: drivers, kernel, cpu, amd-processor

I am using Ubuntu since 2009 on notebooks with Intel CPUs.
However now, that I am using AMD's FX 6300, I am interested in knowing if there exists anything from Ubuntu (specifically any kernel enhancements/drivers/patches) for AMD's FX "family 15h" Piledrivers.

**Reason:** I would like to have a kernel which uses the hardware to its full capacity, be able to use the latest instruction sets, for max. performance.

I did some tests, started with compiling stable 3.9.7 on my 12.04 LTS box, and during compilation I choose processor vendor AMD (unchecked Intel/VIA/etc.), and  when I started  Ubuntu with this compiled kernel, in the section "System Settings -> Additional Drivers" I found that, in addition to graphic card's drivers, there were AMD family 15h drivers also.

However, I would prefer something in this regard  tested/signed by Ubuntu developers.

P.S:
**1-** the kernel that I have compiled has some issues with Nvidia graphics drivers, so I deleted kernel 3.9.7 and installed signed 3.8.xx from Ubuntu repositories.
**2-**  incase if somebody is planning to advise me to install "AMD64", I am not talking about AMD64 (which is in fact for 64-bit platform).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have an answer for you, but how do you like the FX 6300 overall? I am looking at building a new system and want to avoid hardware problems. My last system used the 950 phenom but it looks like there is nothing from AMD anymore besides FX cpus.

Also, what Nvidia are you using? On board or no?

Comment: I have found  FX 6300 an excellent general purpose CPU.
Its performance/price ratio is excellent when compared to Intel's i5.
Although it has only one FPU per module (total=3), but as per my experience, its performance for numerical work is very good.
One side note: This is a dual-boot PC. Windows has some problems with FX 6300, however Linux (I use Ubuntu) gives superb results.

Comment: Since mainboard chipsets for FX series don't come with integrated graphics, so I had to buy a graphic card. Being low on budget, I bought Nvidia GeForce GT 430 (for 30€), which is also a very nice GPU (considering performance/price).

P.S:
I have tested FX-6300 with many benchmarks e.g. SiSoft Sandra WhetStone. My FX-6300 (without overclocking) gives 58GFLOPS (thus beats i5-2500's 55GFLOPS)